# Webscraping - I need some help understanding how to distinguish an item on a page BS4, Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am stuck. I am able to extract product name and prices from amazon, using the following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"}
#
url = f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083PHB6XX'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('span', {'id': 'productTitle'}).text.strip()
price = soup.find('span', {'id': 'priceblock_ourprice'}).text.strip()

print(name)
print(price)
```

But I am unable to figure out how to extract the sales rank data from within the table, which is lower down on the page, under the additional information section. I'd be most grateful if anyone would be able to assist in helping me figure out how to write the next `soup.find` line of code, to show '106,505' for the sales rank.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: ugly but should do `soup.select('#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr:nth-of-type(2) span span').text.split()[0]`

Comment: Thanks!! Could I ask how  you got '#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr:nth-of-type(2) span span'?

Comment: for a full guide, check out [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). here, the first starting with # is the id of the table, then we search for the second `tr`. that's what the pseudo-class `:nth-of-class(2)` does. and finally we search a `span` in another `span`

Comment: You are my  hero!! Thank you so much. I will read and learn. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be searching for `<th>` tag that contains string `"Best Sellers Rank"` and then find next `<span>`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083PHB6XX"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
ranks = soup.select_one('th:-soup-contains("Best Sellers Rank")').find_next(
    "span"
)

print(ranks.text.split()[0])
```

Prints:

```
111,190
```

Comment: There are some clever people on this site! Thank you so much!